# Window background shrinks and sets to custom RelativeLayout, when it clicked

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view

I have a next problem, which happens in 2 cases:

**First case.**

1). I have some custom veiw which draw photos on it with different opacity. here is method MyView.onDraw:

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.getClipBounds(clipRect);
        int i1 = Math.min(testColors.length-1, (int)Math.floor(posX/PHOTO_DISTANCE));
        int c1 = testColors[Math.max(0, i1)];
        int i2 = Math.min(testColors.length-1, (int)Math.ceil(posX/PHOTO_DISTANCE));
        int c2 = testColors[Math.max(0, i2)];
        paint.setColor(c1);
        float r = (255f/PHOTO_DISTANCE*posX)%255;
        paint.setAlpha(255);

        if(photoA != null){//bitmap != null
            bitmapRect.set(0, 0, photoA.getWidth(), photoA.getHeight());
            canvas.drawBitmap(photoA, bitmapRect, clipRect, paint);
        }
        paint.setAlpha((int)(r));
        if(photoB != null){//bitmap != null
            bitmapRect.set(0, 0, photoB.getWidth(), photoB.getHeight());
            canvas.drawBitmap(photoB, bitmapRect, clipRect, paint);
        }
    }
```

testColors - array of colors(int);

photoA, photoB - bitmaps;

i1, i2 - image indexes;

c1, c2 - colors. they are not importatant.

I added this view to FrameView:

```
viewHolder.myFrame.addView(viewHolder.myView, 0);
```

And in this FrameView I have some clickable RelativeLayout's:

```
<com.app.custom.view.ClickableRelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/share_action_container"
                            app1:pressedStateColor="@color/app_pressed_default"
                            app1:unpressedStateColor="@color/color_white"
                            android:background="@color/transparent"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
                            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
                                    android:id="@+id/share_icon"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
                                    <ImageView
                                            android:id="@+id/img_share"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                            android:tag="icon"
                                            android:src="@drawable/ic_share"/>
                            </RelativeLayout>


                            <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                    android:layout_below="@id/share_icon"
                                    android:text="Share"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                                    android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
                                    android:shadowDx="@integer/shadowDX"
                                    android:shadowDy="@integer/shadowDY"
                                    android:shadowRadius="@integer/shadowRadius"
                                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/icon_text_size"
                                    android:tag="text"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:id="@+id/txt_share_action"/>
                    </com.app.custom.view.ClickableRelativeLayout>
```

Here is a Java code of ClickableRelativeLayout:

```
public class ClickableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private ViewHolder viewHolder;
    private int pressedStateColor;
    private int unpressedStateColor;
    private final int DEFAULT_PRESSED_STATE_COLOR;
    private final int DEFAULT_UNPRESSED_STATE_COLOR;

    public ClickableRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        DEFAULT_PRESSED_STATE_COLOR = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.app_pressed_default);
        DEFAULT_UNPRESSED_STATE_COLOR = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.app_blue_without_transparent);
        setup();
        initColors(context, null);
    }

    public ClickableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        DEFAULT_PRESSED_STATE_COLOR = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.app_pressed_default);
        DEFAULT_UNPRESSED_STATE_COLOR = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.app_blue_without_transparent);
        setup();
        initColors(context, attrs);
    }

    public ClickableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        DEFAULT_PRESSED_STATE_COLOR = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.app_pressed_default);
        DEFAULT_UNPRESSED_STATE_COLOR = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.app_blue_without_transparent);
        setup();
        initColors(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setup(){
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    private void initColors(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        if(attrs != null) {
            TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ClickableRelativeLayout);
            pressedStateColor = styledAttributes.getColor(R.styleable.ClickableRelativeLayout_pressedStateColor,
                    DEFAULT_PRESSED_STATE_COLOR);
            unpressedStateColor = styledAttributes.getColor(R.styleable.RowLayout_android_verticalSpacing,
                    DEFAULT_UNPRESSED_STATE_COLOR);
            styledAttributes.recycle();
        }else{
            pressedStateColor = DEFAULT_PRESSED_STATE_COLOR;
            unpressedStateColor = DEFAULT_UNPRESSED_STATE_COLOR;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(
                (TextView) findViewWithTag("text"),
                (ImageView) findViewWithTag("icon")

        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
            if (hasOnClickListeners()) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        select();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        unSelect();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void select(){
        if(isInitializedCorrect()){
            final int color = pressedStateColor;
            viewHolder.text.setTextColor(color);
            ImageHelper.INSTANCE.applyColorFilterToImage(viewHolder.icon.getDrawable(), color);
        }
    }

    private void unSelect(){
        if(isInitializedCorrect()){
            final int color = unpressedStateColor;
            viewHolder.text.setTextColor(color);
            viewHolder.icon.setColorFilter(color);
        }
    }

    private boolean isInitializedCorrect(){
        return viewHolder != null && viewHolder.icon != null && viewHolder.text != null;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView icon;
        TextView text;

        public ViewHolder(TextView text, ImageView icon) {
            this.text = text;
            this.icon = icon;
        }
    }
}
```

And when I clicked on this layout, background of MyView shrinks, and sets to this ClickableRelativeLayout:
[image]
[image]

And **Second case**. 
I have some text view on same frame, it is invisible by default, and when you scrolled 10 photos, I apply AlphaAnimation for this TextView and it draws slowly. Here is a code of alpha animation:

```
AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation1.setDuration(1300);
animation1.setFillAfter(true);
//here is my TextView
viewHolder.gotItView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
viewHolder.gotItView.startAnimation(animation1);
```

And happens the same this. On background of this TextView appears content of MyView